# В каком классе производится взаимодействие с веб приложением

Tags: java, spring, rest

Реализовываю REST приложение, используя Spring. Хотелось бы узнать, как происходит взаимодействие с клиентом, то есть, как получить запрос с клиента и вернуть нужный ответ с сервера.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Взаимодействие с сайтом* происходит через класс контроллера, который должен быть помечен аннотацией `@RestController`, и в свою очередь имеет поле класса-сервиса и некий метод с аннотацией `@GetMapping`:

```java
@RestController
public class PlayerController {

    @Autowired
    private PlayerService playerService;

    @GetMapping("/players")
    public List<Players> allPlayers() {
        return playerService.allPlayers();
    }
}
```

Для версий Spring до 4.0 использовались аннотации `@Controller` и `@ResponseBody`.